# Angular 2 ngIf select box

Tags: html, angular

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="is_present">Is Present?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="is_present" name="is_present" class="form-control" *ngIf="candidates.is_present === true">
      <option value="true">Yes</option>
      <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this code in my html component. I receive a boolean data from API, I would like to know what the best way to use `*ngIf` to add `selected` in `option` tag if the API data is true or false.

Comment: what value you're going to retrieve from the server in `selected`  variable?

Comment: I receive a boolean. I updated the question

Comment: then just `[(ngModel)]="candidates.is_present"` to your select, that's it :) Sajeeth has already gave an answer.

Comment: @VictorMendes I deleted and undeleted my answer, so you won't get notified about the undeletion, so just wanted to point that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly change to Rahul's answer, because from what I understand, you are receiving a boolean value that is should not be the same as `candidates.is_present`. Therefore store the boolean value to a variable, e.g `bool`, and then just have the `[(ngModel)]="bool"` in your select:

```
<select name="is_present" [(ngModel)]="bool" *ngIf="candidates.is_present">
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
  <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **`candidates.is_present`**

```
<select id="is_present" [(ngModel)]="defaultValue" name="is_present" class="form-control">
      <option value="true">Yes</option>
      <option value="false">No</option>
 </select>
```

and in TS file,

```
if(candidates.is_present){
   this.defaultValue = 'Yes';
}else
{ 
   this.defaultValue = 'No';
}
```

Comment: But, if the data is true, how to show the option selected?

Comment: @VictorMendes you can do as above

Answer (score 0):

as i can understand from question you want to select the value in select box based on some candidates.is_present. So here you need to bind the data using [(ngModel)]="candidates.is_present" ,and be sure to include FormsModule in your imports. we use *ngIf when we want our element to remove/add to dom based on some conditions.hope you got the answer